# Parsing through array of dictionaries with Alamofire 4.0 and Swfit 3

Tags: swift, xcode, networking, alamofire

I was wondering how to parse to, get all data from API within Alamofire.

Here is the code that downloads just a one Dictionary of data from API. How can I download other things from it?

Here is screenshot from JSONFormatter:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r33jG.jpg

```
func downloadJsonData (completed: @escaping DownloadCompleted) {
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).responseJSON { response in
        let result = response.result.value
        if let dict = result as? [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>] {

            if let id = dict[0]["id"] as? String {
                self._id = id
                print("@@@\(self._id)")
            }

            if let name = dict[0]["name"] as? String {
                self._name = name
                print("@@@\(self._name)")
            }

            if let avatar = dict[0]["avatar"] as? String {
                self._avatar = avatar
                print("@@@\(self._avatar)")
            }

            if let lat = dict[0]["lat"] as? Float {
                self._lat = lat
                print("@@@\(self._lat)")
            }

            if let lng = dict[0]["lng"] as? Float {
                self._lng = lng
                print("@@@\(self._lng)")
            }
        }
    }
    completed()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func downloadJsonData (completed: @escaping DownloadCompleted) {
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).responseJSON { response in
        if let collectionData = response.result.value as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
            let collection : [YourStruct] = collectionData.flatMap { data in
                guard let id = data["id"] as? String,
                    let name = data["name"] as? String,
                    let avatar = data["avatar"] as? String,
                    let lat = data["lat"] as? Float,
                    let lng = data["lng"] as? Float
                else {
                    return nil
                }

                return YourStruct(id:id, name:name, avatar:avatar, lat:lat, lng:lng)
            }
        }
    }
    completed()
}
```

And now you have a collection of your object. And with it you can do what you want

Comment: well I cannot return Struct. It shows me bug on the 4th line of your code, which says: "unable to infer closure type in the current context"

Comment: Hmm... It is almost perfect, but it itterates over whole array 10 times.. when I'm printing out collectionData, it shows whole bunch of Dictionaries. No idea how to fix that :O

Comment: Where and why you print `collectionData`. After flatMap you have collection of your object (`collection`). and you can print it

Comment: Ahhhh! Okay I understand everything now ! Thank you so much for help :D

Comment: @Tonamini If I helped you then please accept and like my answer

Comment: Yea... I need 2 rep more :D haha

Answer (score 3):

I would really suggest you to use some Object mapper as it make parsing super easy. You can follow below links:

JsonJoy is very easy to use

> https://github.com/daltoniam/JSONJoy-Swift

Or you can check complete detail in below link:

http://harlankellaway.com/blog/2015/07/05/swift-json-parsing-by-example

Otherwise you can go with `Adrian Bobrowski` Answer.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest that you implement a mapping to a custom object, this is a library that helps you with that and can be integrated with Alamofire.

https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper

You can reduce all the boilerplate and is really easy to implement.

Tell me if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Alamofire like this:

```
let Header          = [ "Authorization" : Token ]
let Parameters      = [:]
var json : JSON     = nil
Alamofire.request(URLString, method: method, parameters: Parameters, headers : Header)
    .responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let data):
            json = JSON(data)
            print(json)
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
        }
}
}
```

So after that you can parse your json like this for example:

```
if json != nil {
 let name       = json["name"].stringValue
 let avatar     = json["avatar"].stringValue
 let lng        = json["lng"].doubleValue
 let lat        = json["lat"].doubleValue
}
```

Hope I helped you, Peace